# Regular expression - image is displayed with text

Tags: php, arrays, regex, web-scraping

I am a novice PHP programmer and I was suddenly assinged to get a **scraper** (php) file edited and ready and I am having a problem with it.

```
preg_match_all('/<div class="cloud-zoom-gallery-thumbs">(.*?)<\/div>/s',$html,$resultimg);
        
        $prod_image = trim($resultimg[0][0]);
        preg_match_all('/<img src="(.*?)"/s',$prod_image,$prod_image1); 
                          
        echo "<b>Product Image:&nbsp;</b>";
        print_r($prod_image1);
        
        $prod_thum_image = $prod_image1[1][0];
        echo $prod_image1[1][0];
```

The problem is that the code displays the image but the output is displayed with Array index text like this:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>Here the image is displayed  Array ( [0]
> => http://www.pacificaperfume.com/sites/default/files/styles/product_thumbnail/public/charmed-shadow-palette-new_0.jpg?itok=qZZIeTzG
> ) )
> http://www.pacificaperfume.com/sites/default/files/styles/product_thumbnail/public/charmed-shadow-palette-new_0.jpg?itok=qZZIeTzG

Now I'm new to both php & regular expression, can someone tell me how can I just display the image and not the text. I don't know whether I am clear enough so please bear with me.

Thank-you.

Comment: Use the [`PHPs DOM`](http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) to parse HTML.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot I mean I don't know how plus I've to edit a pre-existing scrapper file written in PHP PRCE...so I am not allowed to do so,anyways Thank-you for your help.

Comment: Delete this line: `print_r($prod_image1);` thats been added by someone to debug

Comment: Deleted it but the image is gone only this is available:

 http://www.pacificaperfume.com/sites/default/files/styles/product_thumbnail/public/charmed-shadow-palette-new_0.jpg?itok=qZZIeTzG

Comment: `echo $prod_image1[0][0];` probably

Comment: Thanks @user574632 I got it, just got it right after trying to delete and add something I don't know how exactly but this worked:


preg_match_all('/<div class="cloud-zoom-gallery-thumbs">(.*?)<\/div>/s',$html,$resultimg);
   
$prod_image = trim($resultimg[0][0]);

preg_match_all('/<img src="(.*?)"/s',$prod_image,$prod_image1); 
   
echo "<b>Product Image:&nbsp;</b>";
print_r($prod_image1[0][0]);
$prod_thum_image = $prod_image1[1][0];

Answer (score 0):

At last this worked fine:

```
preg_match_all('/<div class="cloud-zoom-gallery-thumbs">(.*?)<\/div>/s',$html,$resultimg); $prod_image = trim($resultimg[0][0]); 
preg_match_all('/<img src="(.*?)"/s',$prod_image,$prod_image1);
echo "<b>Product Image:&nbsp;</b>"; 
print_r($prod_image1[0][0]); 
$prod_thum_image = $prod_image1[1][0];
```

I guess I just had to change this:

```
print_r($prod_image1);
```

With this:

```
print_r($prod_image1[0][0]);
```

Else everything remains as it is.Thank-you all for helping me.